# How to publish all flavor variants with Android Gradle Plugin and maven-publish plugin?

Tags: android, maven, gradle

How to publish all flavor variants with Android Gradle Plugin 7+ and maven-publish plugin?

Comment: Add what is the way you are trying to complete it and what's the error that you are facing with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url = "https://yourdomain/repository-${isSnapshot ? 'snapshots/' : 'releases/'}"
                credentials {
                    username mavenUser
                    password mavenPassword
                }
            }
        }
    }
    components.all((component) -> {
        def componentName = component.getName()
        if (componentName.endsWith("_apk")) {
            println("componentName: ${componentName}")
            publishing.publications.create("publication-$componentName", MavenPublication) {
                from component
                groupId = "com.group.id"
                artifactId = "$componentName"
                version = "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}"
            }
        }
    })
}
```